# Is there a quick way of running bash commands in Postgresql psql, like exclamation point in Oracle SQL*Plus?

Tags: postgresql, psql

While working with Oracle SQL*Plus, one can use `"!"` character in order to run shell commands for example

```
SQL>!pwd
```

To see the current working directory.

I would like to know if there is some similar quick way to do the same with Postgresql while using psql.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do that. You use `\!<command>`. Example:

`\!ls`

Here is another example:

```
bkregistration=# \!date
Sun Apr 22 11:13:47 BST 2018
```

This is what it says in the command line documentation:

```
\! [COMMAND]   execute command in shell or start interactive shell
```

Comment: Awesome! Many thanks, I voted up but it says votes by users with less than 15 points reputation will not be visible. Many thanks for your time and your help.